# Is this python code safe against injections?

Tags: python, sockets, code-injection

I have a server/client socket pair in Python. The server receives specific commands, then prepares the response and send it to the client.

In this question, my concern is just about **possible injections** in the code: if it could be possible to ask the server doing something weird with the 2nd parameter -- if the control on the command contents is not sufficient to avoid undesired behaviour.

EDIT:

- according to advices received
- added parameter `shell=True` when calling `check_output` on windows. Should not be dangerous since the command is a plain 'dir'.

.

```
self.client, address = self.sock.accept()

...

cmd = bytes.decode(self.client.recv(4096))
```

`ls`: executes a system command but only reads the content of a directory.

```
if cmd == 'ls':
    if self.linux:
        output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])
    else:
        output = subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True)
    self.client.send(output)
```

`cd`: just calls `os.chdir`.

```
elif cmd.startswith('cd '):
    path = cmd.split(' ')[1].strip()
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        self.client.send(b'is not path')
    else:
        os.chdir(path)
        self.client.send( os.getcwd().encode() )
```

`get`: send the content of a file to the client.

```
elif cmd.startswith('get '):
    file = cmd.split(' ')[1].strip()
    if not os.path.isfile(file):
        self.client.send(b'ERR: is not a file')
    else:
        try:
            with open(file) as f: contents = f.read()
        except IOError as er:
            res = "ERR: " + er.strerror
            self.client.send(res.encode())
            continue

        ... (send the file contents)
```

Comment: There's no way (that I can see) to get your program to execute arbitrary injected code, but sending the contents of arbitrary files could expose too much data or cause permissions errors.

Comment: Also, you never close the files you open, and you shouldn't be wrapping your if/elif conditions in parentheses. Use `with open(file) as f: contents = f.read()` to ensure you don't leave files open, even in case of error.

Comment: why wouldn't you just install an out-of-the-box FTP server?

Answer (score 3):

Except in implementation details, I cannot see any possibilities of *direct injection of arbitrary code* because you do not use received parameters in the only commands you use (`ls -l` and `dir`).

But you may still have some security problems :

- you locate commands through the path instead of using absolute locations. If somebody could change the path environment variable what could happen ... => I advice you to use directly `os.listdir('.')` which is portable and has less risks.
- you seem to have no control on allowed files. If I correctly remember reading `CON:` or other special files on older Windows version gave weird results. And you should **never** give any access to sensible files, configuration, ...
- you could have control on length of asked files to avoid users to try to *break* the server with abnormally long file names.

Answer (score 2):

Typical issues in a client-server scenario are:

- Tricking the server into running a command that is determined by the client. In the most obvious form this happens if the server allows the client to run commands (yes, stupid). However, this can also happen if the client can supply only command parameters but `shell=True` is used. E.g. using `subprocess.check_output('dir %s' % dir, shell=True)` with a client-supplied `dir` variable would be a security issue, `dir` could have a value like `c:\ && deltree c:\windows` (a second command has been added thanks to the flexibility of the shell's command line interpreter). A relatively rare variation of this attack is the client being able to influence environment variables like `PATH` to trick the server into running a different command than intended.
- Using unexpected functionality of built-in programming language functions. For example, `fopen()` in PHP won't just open files but fetch URLs as well. This allows passing URLs to functionality expecting file names and playing all kinds of tricks with the server software. Fortunately, Python is a sane language - `open()` works on files and nothing else. Still, database commands for example can be problematic if the SQL query is generated dynamically using client-supplied information ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).
- Reading data outside the allowed area. Typical scenario is a server that is supposed to allow only reading files from a particular directory, yet by passing in `../../../etc/passwd` as parameter you can read any file. Another typical scenario is a server that allows reading only files with a particular file extension (e.g. `.png`) but passing in something like `passwords.txt\0harmless.png` still allows reading files of other types.

Out of these issues only the last one seems present in your code. In fact, your server doesn't check at all which directories and files the client should be allowed to read - this is a potential issue, a client might be able to read confidential files.